# How to save changes made to jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

My question is , how to save changes made to jTable?

I want to save changes made to jTable by adding
 save button in my program, but I don't know the source code of save button.

Please Help , can anybody send me the source code of save button.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yet?

Comment: You use the TableModel `getValueAt(...)` method to get the data from each row/column and then you save it somewhere. How you save the data is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend saving your data in a output file. Going off of [camickr's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr) point, you can use the accessibility of JTable to help you save the data. To do this, I recommend using a [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html). I can try to help you with the data types more if you specify what kind of data you are trying to save. I have attached a simple implementation of the PrintWriter class that saves a string.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Testing {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
  {
    File file = new File ("file.txt");
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter ("file.txt");
    printWriter.println ("hello");
    printWriter.close ();       
  }
}
```

This class will save the word "hello" to a file called "file.txt".